# "crosshair" in MS excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Sometimes it is hard to see which cells are in the row/column of the selected cell in excel. Is there an option which would enable "crosshair", which would bold not only selected cells, but also cells in the same row/column as the selected one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for quick and detailed answer!

Comment: This works slow as hell (really - it takes 8 seconds and huge CPU load to switch the highligted cell, this is ridiculous and hardly tolerable) and erases the colours customized previously.

Comment: If you get the issue described by @Ivan you may want to check [this](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/locate-and-reset-the-last-cell-on-a-worksheet-c9e468a8-0fc3-4f69-8038-b3c1d86e99e9) as that would affect the number of cells excel has to work through